# How to print output in a file after a few empty lines

Tags: c++, file-io

What I want to do here, is print the word "hello", first at the beginning, then skip some lines, then print it again in the file. The number of lines I need to skip is specified by the user. The file may or may not be empty, and if it's not empty, I don't want to change data on lines other than I need to print. If the file is empty, then it has to skip empty lines and still print after some lines.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream f1("temp.txt");
    ofstream f2("temp.txt");

    int r;
    cout << "Enter number of lines to skip:" ;
    cin >> r;

    f2 << "hello";
    string org = "";

    while(--r){

        getline(f1, org);

        cout << "org: "<< endl;

    }

    int pos = f1.tellg();
    cout << "pos: " << pos << endl;
    f2.seekp(pos, f2.beg);
    f2 << "hello";

}
```

The output I receive when I input r=3, for example, and the file is empty:

```
org: 
org: 
pos: -1
```

Also, the file remains empty. No output. 
tellg() does not seem to work. 
Anyone has any idea what to do here?

Comment: You can't read from and write to the same file like that. Use a temporary file for the output, and then "rename" it as the original file (after you closed both files).

Comment: You are trying to do too many new things at once. Break the problem down into smaller, simpler problems, and tackle them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't read and write to the same file. Files are opened in different modes so this won't work. But aside from that it is also better practice to parse your input, then operate on it in memory and write out the desired result. so open the file, read what is of interest (you can store a map with the lines that are interesting, or read the whole thing into memory) then do your operations on it, and write out the result.